# MainApplication.java in React Native 0.61.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, package

I'm migrating my project from React Native 0.59.9 to 0.61.0 (not advisable, but I have my own reasons). In my existing project I have the following code in `MainApplication.java`:

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      RollbarReactNative.getPackage(),
      new VectorIconsPackage(),
      new RNTextInputMaskPackage(),
      new SplashScreenReactPackage(),
      new RNSensitiveInfoPackage(),
      new ReactNativeRestartPackage(),
      new PickerViewPackage(),
      new LinearGradientPackage(),
      new ImagePickerPackage(),
      new RNGestureHandlerPackage(),
      new RNDeviceInfo(),
      new A0Auth0Package(),
      new AsyncStoragePackage()
  );
}
```

In `MainApplication.java` in v0.61.0 the following code is auto-generated (corresponds to the code above):

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
  List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
  // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
  // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
  return packages;
}
```

Does it make sense that I would add the packages from the first part of the code to the second like:

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
  List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
  // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
  // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
  packages.add(new MainReactPackage())
  packages.add(RollbarReactNative.getPackage())
  packages.add(new VectorIconsPackage())
  packages.add(new RNTextInputMaskPackage())
  packages.add(new SplashScreenReactPackage())
  packages.add(new RNSensitiveInfoPackage())
  packages.add(new ReactNativeRestartPackage())
  packages.add(new PickerViewPackage())
  packages.add(new LinearGradientPackage())
  packages.add(new ImagePickerPackage())
  packages.add(new RNGestureHandlerPackage())
  packages.add(new RNDeviceInfo())
  packages.add(new A0Auth0Package())
  packages.add(new AsyncStoragePackage())
  return packages;
}
```

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to add the packages anymore. RN0.60 and above supports auto-linking. I commented out my packages because they are no longer needed.
[image]

You will definitely get a similar warning as the image below if you add them.
[image]

Comment: Have you had any problems with this since it's a new feature?

Comment: No, I haven't. You may find some packages does not support auto-liking best thing to do is to let the developer know so they can change it but most packages now do.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've found a module that doesn't support auto-linking already. When I go into XCode and open the Libraries folder that previously (before auto-linking) contained my native modules, it's empty. For modules that don't support auto-linking, should I still add them manually in here as I did in the past?

Comment: Yeah, you can but what module is that?

Comment: By the way, for ios. When you install a module that requires linking you need to update the pods `cd ios` and `pod update` or `pod install`

Comment: The module is Rollbar: https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-react-native
I've actually never used CocoaPods. I've been using React Native for about a year and have seen reference to pods all over the place, but never needed to use them. Is there something I'm missing? Are they needed?

Comment: Yeah, you need CocoaPods for ios. Rollbar supports auto-linking. If you have cocoaPods installed on your pc. Do `cd ios` and do `pod install`

Comment: Any idea why I haven't run into this before? I've made a couple big projects, and there's a Podfile in my ios folder by default, but I've never run `pod install`. I approved your answer btw, thanks for you help.

Comment: I think it's because you were using a version lower than 0.60. I spent hours as well trying to upgrade from 0.59 to 0.60 before finally getting everything to work. Thanks for approving, glad to help. FYI: everytime you change a version of any linked packages you need to do `pod update`.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to go through a tutorial on CocoaPods with React Native, but to clarify what you've told me, whenever I add a native module, do `pod install` from the ios folder, and `pod update` (and then `pod install` again?) whenever I upgrade one of the native modules? For packages that use autolinking, do I still need to do this, or would I do `pod install` only for packages that don't support auto-linking yet?

Comment: whenever you add a native module, do `pod install`. When you upgrade or remove a module do `pod update` . That's it. For packages that don't support auto linking you will have to manually link them.

Comment: Ok thanks. Last question, what's the basic difference between Pods and native modules as I've been using them? I've always used `react-native link`, and then any modules that failed to link, I added manually by dragging into the Libraries folder and dragging the `.a` file to the Link Binaries folder. What's the difference between this process and `pod install`?

Comment: Autolinking is a mechanism built into CLI that allows adding a dependency with native components for React Native to be as simple as:

`yarn add react-native-webview`

Autolinking is a replacement for `react-native link` that brings new features (such as the ability to easily integrate native dependencies on iOS) and fixes some of the long-standing issues.

`pod install` is just an extra step for iOS. I’m not actually sure why auto-linking doesn’t just run it by itself.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks again for your help, I upvoted all comments.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using RN > 0.60 , it's no longer needed to add packages manually in your MainApplication.java file as they are auto-linked